# issue where Flask app request handling is choked when a regex.serach is happening?

Tags: python, regex, multithreading, flask

Setup :

- Language i am using is Python
- I am running a flask app with `threaded =True` and inside the flask app when an endpoint is hit, it starts a thread and returns a thread started successfully with status code 200.
- Inside the thread, there is re.Search happening, which takes 30-40 seconds(worst case) and once the thread is completed it hits a callback URL completing one request.
- Ideally, the Flask app is able to handle concurrent requests

Issue:

When the re.search is happening inside the thread, the flask app is not accepting concurrent requests. I am assuming some kind of thread locking is happening and unable to figure out.

Question :

1. is it ok to do threading(using multi processing) inside flask app which has "threaded = True"?
2. When regex is happening does it do any thread locking?

Code snippet: hit_callback does a post request to another api which is not needed for this issue.

```
import threading
from flask import *
import re
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route(/text)
def temp():
    text = request.json["text"]
    def extract_company(text)


        attrib_list = ["llc","ltd"] # realone is 700 in length
        entity_attrib = r"((\s|^)" + r"(.)?(\s|$)|(\s|^)".join(attrib_list) + r"(\s|$))"
        raw_client = re.search("(.*(?:" + entity_attrib + "))", text, re.I)

        hit_callback(raw_client)

    extract_thread = threading.Thread(target=extract_company, )
    extract_thread.start()

    return jsonify({"Response": True}), 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=4557, threaded=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read up on the GIL - basically, Python can only execute ONE piece of code at the same time - even if in threads. So your re-search runs and blocks all other threads until run to completion.

Solutions: Use Gunicorn etc. pp to run multiple flask processes - do not attempt to do everything in one flask process.

To add something: Also your design is problematic - 40 seconds or so for a http answer is way to long. A better design would have at least two services: a web server and a search service. The first would register a search and give back an id. Your search service would communicate asynchronously with the web service and return resullt +id when the result is ready. Your clients could pull the web service until they get a result.

Comment: ok, got it. in the last like you meant pool right? I will look into Gunicorn. We are moving to web server approach soon. I just wanted to understand the issue here. Can you please comment on pp to run multiple flask process.